# show product list on magento homepage AFTER filter (layered nav) is selected

Tags: jquery, css, xml, magento

At this moment i have a homepage with

- leftside layered navigation
- a product list.
- 3 blocks (new, sale and bestseller products).

(btw i use magento 1.9.2.1)

What i want to achieve is only the 3 blocks (new, sale and bestseller). And the layered navigation.

As soon as one of the filters in the layered navigation is selected the 3 blocks remove (or at least pushed down) and then the product list shows up.

Maybe i can use jQuery (with a boolean like: if filter is true then...) to toggle between the display for the product list -> but which filter is globally available for the "if filter is true".
Or.. jQuery is not the solution and some layout xml update is better?

I would like your advice. Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to go down the jQuery route (probably not the best?) You could potentially hide the product list using CSS on page load.  Then use `template/catalog/layer/state.phtml` to determine if there are active filters, and add jQuery/prototype to show the product listing div at that point only?  If you removed all the filters, (assuming you're using standard Magento) it would just default to not showing again.

Comment: thank you, but you write "probably not the best?", i agree with that but i can't think of another way. In which direction would you solve this? XML layout updates/ customize the layered navigation behavior?